# How to change apk file and resign it onilne?

Tags: android, sign

For some security reasons I need to change apk file before user can download apk file. But when I change .apk content, my app cant be installed. Its need to be resigned.

So I want to know how do I resign it using only zip-open/read/write operations or something else using php.

The only way I see is to install sdk tools on server and work with them with shell command in php. But I want to know if there are more easy ways to do this

Comment: Why do you want to `change the apk file before user can download apk file`?

Comment: I need to add one file into the assets folder of the application online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only way I see is to install sdk tools on server and work with them with shell command in php.

In all likelihood, that is your only option. Even if somehow PHP had a fully-functioning `jarsigner` embedded in it, it is unlikely to also have `zipalign`.

Note, though, that by "sdk tools", you only really need the Java SDK (for `jarsigner`) and the `zipalign` binary (which, AFAIK, has no other dependencies). You should not need the entire Android SDK.